# React Js: SyntaxError: Unexpected token w in JSON at position 0

Tags: reactjs

I am using fetch to make rest post call from reactjs.It works perfectly,but i can't convert the response into a json format.When i try to convert the response into an json format it shows above error.

This is my code to make a rest post call

```
httpCalling(data) {
          return fetch('http://localhost:8080/testingonly', {
            method:'POST',
            mode:'CORS',
            body:JSON.stringify({uname:"sfdfdsf"}),
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                 'Acc': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(res =>{
            console.log(res);
            return res.json();
        })
    }
```

response is

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:8080/testingonly",redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body:(...)
bodyUsed
:
true
headers
:
Headers {}
ok
:
true
redirected
:
false
status
:
200
statusText
:
"OK"
type
:
"cors"
url
:
"http://localhost:8080/testingonly"
__proto__
:
Response
```

Comment: It means JSON is not of correct format. Can you post what you are getting as response?

Comment: `Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:8080/testingonly", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body
:
(...)
bodyUsed
:
true
headers
:
Headers {}
ok
:
true
redirected
:
false
status
:
200
statusText
:
"OK"
type
:
"cors"
url
:
"http://localhost:8080/testingonly"
__proto__
:
Response`

Comment: can you edit your question with it? Its hard to understand here

Comment: Can you post the response when you query it from postman? You are showing the fetch request object

Comment: i thought that was response

Comment: OP is trying to convert the body to JSON which is what's throwing the error. We need to see the body of the response not the request object. Postman will show us this

Comment: Yes he is. That is trying to convert the body of the response to JSON. We need to see the raw response body before he tries to parse to JSON as there is likely some malformed JSON in there.

Comment: tried with postman it gives correct result

Comment: it still showing same error when i changed the data sent to the server